# Showing only relevant columns

Tags: text-processing, rhel

I have the following command.

```
(head -1 invoice.txt  && sed '1d' invoice.txt |sort -rn -k4,4) |column -ts $'\t' |less -S
```

- `head -1` prints the first line.
- `sed "1d'` removes the first line so soft wont be confused
- `sort -rn -k4,4` sorts my file by the 4th column only
- `column -ts $'\t'` splits the file by tab
- `less -S` prints it on the terminal

I would like to print only the first, fourth  and last column. This is a small file however I have one with fourteen and one with twenty one columns, that i will use this template on.

And I am not sure if to use `cut`, `awk`, `print` or other command to pipe for my current output.

Comment: this is a working output, you need to remove the first line or the sorft will not work

Comment: Oh, sorry, I see what you're doing now. The formatting of the command confused me.

Answer (score 0):

You want to show only the 1st, 4th and last tab-delimited columns, and you want to sort the data on the second of those columns numerically, ignoring the header.

```
awk -F '\t' 'BEGIN { OFS=FS } { print $1, $4, $NF }' invoice.txt >tmpfile

{
    head -n 1 tmpfile
    sed '1d' tmpfile | sort -k 2,2rn
} | less -S
```

Or, you could bypass the temporary file and just pass everything from `awk` into the `{ ...; }` compound command via a pipe. Add `column -ts $'\t'` before `less -S` if needed.